# Prove $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt{(n+a)(n+b)}-n=\frac{a+b}2$

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

Prove $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt{(n+a)(n+b)}-n=\frac{a+b}2.$$

I have found the preceding problem in the Calculus book (Bartle & Sherbert) where I am asked to demonstrate the previous limit assuming $a>0$, $b>0$.

I have been trying for an hour, but I cannot see how I can demonstrate it.

Comment: multiply and divide by the conjugate.

Comment: The usual trick for these is to multiply and divide by the conjugate: $\sqrt{(n+a)(n+b)}+n$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**. One may write, as $n \to \infty$,
\begin{align}
\sqrt{(n+a)(n+b)}-n&=\frac{\left(\sqrt{(n+a)(n+b)}-n\right)\left(\sqrt{(n+a)(n+b)}+n\right)}{\sqrt{(n+a)(n+b)}+n}\\\\
&=\frac{(n+a)(n+b)-n^2}{\sqrt{(n+a)(n+b)}+n}
\end{align}
Hope you can take it from here.

Comment: (+1) to have let some work to the asker

Answer (score 1):

Remember that $$\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y}= {x-y\over \sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}}$$
so

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt{(n+a)(n+b)} -n = \lim_{n \to \infty} {(n+a)(n+b) -n^2 \over \sqrt{(n+a)(n+b)} +n}$$

$$= \lim_{n \to \infty} {n\Big((a+b)+{ab\over n}\Big) \over n(\sqrt{(1+{a\over n})(1+{b\over n})} +1)}$$

$$=\frac{a+b}{2}$$

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

As an alternative by binomial expansion $$(1+x)^n=1+xn+o(x) \quad x\to 0$$

we have

$$\sqrt{(n+a)(n+b)} -n =n\sqrt{1+\frac a n}\sqrt{1+\frac b n} -n =$$$$= n\left(1+\frac a {2n}+o\left(\frac1n\right)\right)\left(1+\frac b {2n}+o\left(\frac1n\right)\right)-n=\ldots$$

Comment: Yes nice too (+1).

Answer (score 1):

You may consider this sequence limit in the context of the AGM inequality, relating the geometric and the arithmetic mean. The identity
$$\sqrt{XY}\;=\;\frac{X+Y}2\:-\:\frac12\left(\sqrt X - \sqrt Y\,\right)^2$$
is a "quantitative AGM version" since the last term involving the square measures the spread between the geometric and the arithmetic mean.

Now let $\,X=n+a, Y=n+b,\,$ and subtract $n$ to obtain
$$\sqrt{(n+a)(n+b)}-n\;=\;\frac{a+b}2
\:-\:\frac12\left(\sqrt{n+a}-\sqrt{n+b}\,\right)^2$$
The last term is obviously a null sequence, each element of which is negative (if $a\neq b$).

Thus the limit is approached from below.